# Convert List<Object> in Map<attributeA,List<attributeB>

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, mapping

```
public class Test {

  public void foo() {

  ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

  persons.add(new Person("Marco", "Bianchi"));
  persons.add(new Person("Marco", "Rossi"));
  persons.add(new Person("Marco", "Verdi"));
  persons.add(new Person("Giacomo", "Bianchi"));
  persons.add(new Person("Giacomo", "Rossi"));
  persons.add(new Person("Giacomo", "Verdi"));

  Map<String, List<String>> map = ??
} 

class Person {
    String name;
    String surname;

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
       return surname; 
}
```

I need to have `Map<Name, List<Surname>>` when `Name` is equal and `Surname` is in the List. 
Expected result:

> { Marco=[Bianchi, Rossi, Verdi], Giacomo=[Bianchi, Rossi, Verdi] }

Can you help me?

I need lambda function solution.

Comment: Hint: details matter. Next time: post code that compiles. Actually your input isn't exactly great quality. Check out the help center to understand better how/what to ask here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8 take a look at Stream API.
Here is an example how easy it is to solve you task:

```
public class MapExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

        people.add(new Person("Marco", "Bianchi"));
        people.add(new Person("Marco", "Rossi"));
        people.add(new Person("Marco", "Verdi"));
        people.add(new Person("Giacomo", "Bianchi"));
        people.add(new Person("Giacomo", "Rossi"));
        people.add(new Person("Giacomo", "Verdi"));

        Map<String, List<String>> map = people.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName,
                    Collectors.mapping(Person::getSurname, Collectors.toList()))
            );
    }
}
```

With static import it looks more declarative:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

// ....

Map<String, List<String>> map = people.stream()
        .collect(
                groupingBy(Person::getName, mapping(Person::getSurname, toList()))
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Person p : people) {
    List<String> surnames = map.get(p.getName());
    if (surnames == null) {
        surnames = new ArrayList<>();
        map.put(p.getName(), surnames);
    }
    surnames.add(p.getSurname());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Map<String, List<String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (person aPerson : persons) {
  List<String> surnames;
  if (map.contains(aPerson.name)) {
    surnames = map.get(aPerson.name); }
  else {
     surnames = new ArrayList<>();
     map.put(aPerson.name, surnames);
  }
  surnames.add(aPerson.surname;
}
```

But of course, many things to improve in your code:

1. Class names start UpperCase. Always. So it should be **P**erson
2. Your Person class should make its fields private; and have getters for it.
3. Your Person class should probably implement equals() and hashcode() in a reasonable way.

Comment: I agree with first and second advices. But what is the reason to add equals() and hashCode()? Person isn't a key for hash table.

Comment: Well, it looks like a typical "value" class. So, sooner or later, it would be just useful to have that. That is why I said "probably".

Answer (score 0):

Try to use apache common [MultiValuedMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html):

```
MultivaluedMap<String, Object> map = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("Marco", "Bianchi");
map.put("Marco", "Rossi");
map.put("Marco", "Verdi");
map.put("Giacomo", "Bianchi");
map.put("Giacomo", "Rossi");
map.put("Giacomo", "Verdi");
```

For getting the value from the map, iterate it and you will get the list of value i.e:

```
Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
for(String key : keySet){
   System.out.println(key + " ==> " + map.get(key));
}
```

output:
Marco ==> ["Bianchi","Rossi","Verdi"]
Giacomo ==> ["Bianchi","Rossi","Verdi"]

Hope..This will help you. :D